# Write script for Corel Draw

Tags: automation, corel-draw, sprite, script

Is it possible to write script in some language which would generate vectors for me automatically in the way I want? In Corel Draw of course.

I have 30 basic images and I want to make a spritesheet with them, but I have to go over 30 times doing the same thing which is boring thing to do.

Check the images below:

[image][image]

Let just say I have to create spritesheets like these in the images but from numbers 10 to 40. So you would have to do 30 time copy paste etc...

How would go about doing it in Corel Draw?

Is this a question for StackOverflow?

Comment: Ok I will try with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could be done with a script, surely. But it might take longer to write and test the script than to do it manually.

Since it looks like you're doing a transform, then blending between them. Would the blend tool work for partial automation?

Comment: Well, I might need to change some of the images in future so a script would do nicely. However I don't know VisualBasic or either how to run a basic script in Corel so I will export just the basic images as PNGs and then use PHP to generate the spritesheets with a code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Basically there are two parts, first generate oppening animation than second, generate closing animation. They are the same but just in reverse order.

Comment: It might be a good excuse to learn VisualBasic, but it won't be quicker for a long long time. Keep with Corel, it's the best of the current Vector apps. Corel Designer is even kind of cool.

Comment: Yup, true, I find PHP very confortable to use for small tasks like this.

Comment: I had no idea there was such a thing as a "good excuse" to learn Visual Basic, isn't that like dividing by zero? ;)

Comment: Haha! Comon now. VisualBasic is much improved from its early days. Now it's like pulling teeth, where it was like lopping off the head in the early days ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend tackling this problem as a print merge: prepare a text file with the numbers you'll be needing (1 per line), then use it to perform a print merge on a readymade design, with the number from your text file inputted into each card that requires it. Then perform the merge - you should end up with 40 pages (or however many numbers you had) of designs like the one above, each with a different number on the cards.

Then you can print to PDF and export images from the PDF...

Comment: Nice trick. Worth giving a try. But I already finished all using coded php script :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured, judging by the date :) Thought somebody else might find it useful though, just in case